# Passport JS / mySQL (Deserialize Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined

Tags: javascript, mysql, passport.js

I am in the process of migrating my user account system from MongoDB to mySQL. Everything was working great, until I Deserialize my user on login. Once I get to this point, I get:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of
>   undefined.

In my deserialize function, I have two functions, one referencing mySQL and one referencing my MongoDB query.

When I enable the mySQL function, I get the error. But when I reference the MongoDB function using a hard coded _id. I get a success.

Please help.. This has had me hung up for at least 5 hrs.

```
passport.deserializeUser(async function(id, done) {
    dbs.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE `_id` = "' + id + '";', function(err, user){
        if (err) throw err;
        var u = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user[0]));
        console.log('attempted return')
        console.log(u); //Returns an obj
        done(err, u);
    });

    User.getUserById("59c2fc904300338c08a8359c", function(err, user) {
        console.log(user);
        //done(err, user);
    });
});
```

My Log on login is:

```
   attempted return
{ _id: 2,
  username: 'TINA',
  email: 'tina@gmail.com',
  password: '1234',
  name: 'TIN',
  super_user: 0 }
(node:105576) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined
(node:105576) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
{ _id: 59c2fc904300338c08a8359c,
  name: 'Ryan Igo',
  email: 'rigo@cfevans.com',
  username: 'rigo',
  password: '$2a$10$doYAezUZ/bzOFKQEbTPrTOb2RiF33cH3N8G/N/nuxaKFvzpFjC6H.',
  __v: 0,
  procore_projects:
   [ ],
  procore_companies: [],
  procore:
   { created_at: '1506083587',
     refresh_token: '4e4d6c962884671e116938141de707b59eab8c442f8ae39bdad79255b6b183da',
     expires_in: '7200',
     access_token: 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJFUzUxMiJ9.eyJhaWQiOiI3NDNkNmJiYzYyNGNiMWM5YzU2MDczMzMzMzgwY2FlN2QzN2Y0ODQ0NTgwZTFiZGIxZDM2MzAwNTgzZjg3ZTEwIiwiZXhwIjoxNTA2MDkwNzg3LCJ1aWQiOjI3NzkxOH0.AD9Sk2AcsLLrH1OtCUg8cnh3tOFq5vyQTetsBN1J29anrUXEr2nW40rENmkZLj1wPxfjnhW0Vp03spEYYAr-MRB7AFX9HgUQ_5sUa34hgbg0Vd5biwX4FluhqSJ8_73lEsO59xPSedpmD_vQC7dwaAa4NU8uVhhMm6VaDYCXrHvGZ74N' } }
```

Comment: Is `user` a string or a JavaScript object?

Comment: user is an object returned from mysql. I get the same if error if i return user[0] in the callback of the dbs.query()